# Bash script with basic if/else and count of processes running based on a pattern

Tags: bash, scripting, shell

I'm trying to write a script that counts the number of processes running matching a patern. If it exceeds a hardcoded value then do something...else do something else.

I am finding out the count of processes using:

```
ps ax | grep process_name | wc -l | sed -e "s: ::g"
```

If the output of the above command is greater than 15..it should echo "Done". Otherwise, echo "Not Complete".

So far, I have this but it isn't working:

```
numprocesses=ps ax | grep sms_queue | wc -l | sed -e "s: ::g"
if [ $numprocesses -le "15" ] ; then
  echo "Done."
else
  echo "Not Complete."
fi
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
numprocesses=$(ps ax | grep '[s]ms_queue' | wc -l)
if [[ $numprocesses -gt 15 ]] ; then
  echo "Done."
else
  echo "Not Complete."
fi
```

You had a few problems.

- Your if statement didn't quite match your specification.
- To capture the output of the `xyz` command, you should use `$(xyz)`.
- No need for stripping spaces from the output.
- If you don't want to pick up the `grep` process as well (because it too has the pattern it's looking for), you should use the `[firstchar]rest` grep pattern (or you can use `| grep sms_queue | grep -v grep` to remove the `grep` process from the count as well.
- no need to use the *string* "15" in the comparison.

Comment: As this answer is listing all sorts of improvements into addition to the primary mistake, I'd like to add the suggestion to use an arithmetic expression: `if (($numprocesses > 15)); then ...`. That's nicer to read.

Comment: @paxdiablo: don't you really think that *string* "15" is any different from your *number* 15? :)

Comment: @MForster: this is even less portable than `[[ ]]` stuff. I'd advise to use plain old `[` aka `test`.

Comment: It is correct that `[[...]]` and `((...))` are less portable than `[...]`. This is a classical trade-off between portability and maintainability. For me I made the choice to focus on maintainability, because all environments I care about have a recent version of bash.

Comment: @MForster: How is it more maintainable?

Comment: The tags to the question stated `bash` - I think you'll find both `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` are portable within that domain.

Comment: These constructs are more maintainable, because they are more readable, and because they don't have some of the odd behaviors of `[...]`, for example handling empty strings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the output of a command into a variable use this syntax:

```
variable=$(my command)
```

Comment: That's correct, but I think that `$(...)` is preferable. It is easier to read (can't be confused with `'...'`) and can be nested.

Comment: @MForster: backticks can be nested too (although only one-level deep)

Comment: To clarify: my definition of nesting is "using the syntactical construct within itself". In that definition it does not make sense to talk about one-level deep nesting. I'm referring to the fact that I can use `echo $(basename $(dirname /usr/local/bin/))` but not the same using backticks (no idea how to format that in markdown).

Comment: Even better is `variable="$(my command)"`. Even if there is a quoted argument inside the command, bash will handle it properly.

Comment: @Benoit: there won't be any difference in variable assignment.

Comment: @Roman Cheplyaka: maybe, but it is always better to take good habits.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
pgrep -c sms_queue
```

?

And the whole (portable) version of the script would look like this:

```
if [ "$(pgrep -c sms_queue)" -le 15 ]; then
  echo "Done."
else
  echo "Not Complete."
fi
```

Comment: Portable? That's interesting. Your script doesn't seem to run in `csh`. Or was this some self-serving definition of portable I've not heard before? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: It was POSIX definition. I'm well aware that this script won't run in csh, perl, and most other interpreters of different scripting languages.